# How do I extract meta tag content using CSS selectors in Gatling check?

Tags: css-selectors, gatling

My page has a meta tag containing the csrf token:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="somestring">
```

I'd like to use css-selectors to grab the content:

```
action.check(css("meta[name=\"_csrf\"]", "content").saveAs("x-csrf-token"))
```

However, this fails with the error:

```
css((meta,Some(content))).find(0).exists, found nothing
```

What is the correct way to extract the content of the meta tag?

Comment: your example looks good, and seems to work for me. Using gatling 3.1 I can make `.check(css("meta[name=\"robots\"]", "content").saveAs("robots"))` work on a page which has `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to produce a more minimal test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, the issue was malformed html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <head>
        </head>
        <meta name="_csrf" content="abc123">
    </head>
</html>
```

Browsers ignored the bad markup, but Gatling/whatever library it uses under the hood did not.

I have not yet investigated whether this is a bug or should/could be easily changed.